# Add mutliple pass in apple wallet

Tags: ios, wallet, passkit

My app has a requirement to add multiple passes (a group of the pass) in apple wallet

I have PKAddPassesViewController, and it has a method to add multiple passes but after adding in it, it shows only 1 pass.

```
//destinationURLs are download file URL
let pkfile1 : Data = try! Data(contentsOf: destinationURL1)
let pkfile2 : Data = try! Data(contentsOf: destinationURL2)
var pkPasses = [PKPass]()
let pass : PKPass = PKPass(data: pkfile1 as Data, error: nil)
let pass1 : PKPass = PKPass(data: pkfile2 as Data, error: nil)
pkPasses.append(pass)
pkPasses.append(pass1)

let vc = PKAddPassesViewController(passes: pkPasses) as PKAddPassesViewController
vc.delegate = self
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController!.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

With this code, I get only 1 proper formatted graph

my screenshot of PKAddPassesViewController's passes

[image]

Comment: can you try to slide left or right to see if the 2 passes are present?

Comment: I already check but i didn't get any other pass or tickets.

Comment: what makes a pass unique is the pass type identifier and serial number fields. can you check if you passes have the same (pass type id + S/N)?

Comment: @HichemBOUSSETTA, we have a different pass/tickets from our own app but pass type identifier and serial number is the same because ticket/pass generated from our app

Comment: you need to use a different serial number for each pass you generate, otherwise they will be considered the same.

Comment: As per @passkit solution, we have to generate a random serial number for each pass to getting solved this issue.

Comment: Yep! And avoid using full random serial number ;-)

Comment: Yes and after random generate the serial number, we have to convert it in a string format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, pass and pass1 contain the same data.

Your comment above explains why you are only seeing one pass, because passes are uniquely indexed by certificate and serial number.

Wallet won't allow 2 passes with the same index, so your second pass is most likely overwriting your first. Use a different serial number when generating your second pass and you will have no problem.

Comment: sorry for added same pkfile by mistake but both passes have different pkpass,kindly check my edited my code.

Comment: But if they both have the same serial number you will only see one card in the wallet.

Comment: I think serial number is unique for an application. am i right?

Comment: No, the serial number needs to be unique for the pass.  When you update a pass, Wallet uses a composite of the passTypeId and seralNumber to index the pass.  If these are both the same, the pass is updated.  So your second pass, with the same passTypeId and serialNumber is updating your first one - this is why you only see one pass in the wallet.  Make the serial on the second pass different and your problem will be fixed.

Comment: My app requirement has an event and an event has 2 or more types of pass (platinum, gold ) so how can I change my pass type id and serial number for 2nd pass because I generate 1 passtype ID for my application so is it require that  different passtype ID for different passes?

Comment: Serial number needs to be unique for each pass - just use a random generator, or use a different serial for platinum and gold. There’s no other way around it - it is used as an index and quite clearly explained in the documentation.

Comment: But you told me in your answer is like "passes are uniquely indexed by certificate and serial number" so how can I change serial number because my serial number is uniquely identified with my passtype certificate.

Comment: No - the index forms a composite key that can identify any individual pass bearing your passTypeId.  Other passTypeId holders are free to set their own serials, which is why serial on it’s own can not be used as an index.  Just change the serial of the second pass - that’s all you need to do.  There is absolutely no way to have 2 passes with the same passTypeId and serialNumber in a single wallet.

Comment: you are right, I have updated my pass ID and generated randomly and my issue is solved.